# hide vertical and horizontal scrollbars

Tags: css

[image]See picture. How do I hide the horizontal and vertical scrolls bars in the div. I use

```
width: 100%;
height: 250px;
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: visible;
white-space: nowrap;
```

I want to allow scrolling horizontally (but hide the scrollbars) and anything that overflows vertically should be shown to the user.

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="shell">
    <div class="overlay-shell-content">
        <div class="area">
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="related">
                    <h4>More like this:</h4>
                    <div class="related-items clearfix">
..... 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not clear what you want, you want to hide? or show?

Comment: `overflow:auto;` is enough for this.

Comment: The scrollbars still show.....

Comment: can you post `html` also?

Comment: As in pic, your content is already overflown the container, so the scroll bars will show.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll/16671476#16671476

Comment: In CSS, `::-webkit-scrollbar` functionalities may help as it can hide it but not disable the scrolling. Take note for cross browser support.